# Why has my question been deleted?

Tags: discussion, networking

I asked a question about NFSv4 and FreeBSD and it got deleted? Why?

Answer (score 12):

Your [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/779850/freebsd-server-freebsd-client-when-trying-to-mount-at-version-4-nfsv4-error-100) has been [autodeleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173513/turbocharging-the-roomba-solutions-for-premature-deletion/177675#177675) by the system because it had negative votes and no activity (no views, no comments or answers) for 30 days.